# Difficulties with Matlab12b function imshow()

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm using MATLAB for image processing and I came across a code with the instruction:

```
imshow(pixel_labels,[]);
```

when executed it give a binary image.

I have check the manual of the function on Mathworks.com, the most similar used mode is

```
imshow(I,[low,high]);
```

but they don't say a thing about the case where that array is empty (`[]`)

I tried to remove it:

```
imshow(pixel_labels);
```

but all I see is a white board. I would like to know what is happening in the first use case (`imshow(pixel_labels,[])`), I hope from there I will understand why I get a white board in the last use case.

Answer (score 2):

If I type `help imshow` in MATLAB, the first paragraph reads:

> IMSHOW(I,[LOW HIGH]) displays the grayscale image I, specifying the
>   display
>       range for I in [LOW HIGH]. The value LOW (and any value less than LOW)
>       displays as black, the value HIGH (and any value greater than HIGH) displays
>       as white. Values in between are displayed as intermediate shades of gray,
>       using the default number of gray levels. If you use an empty matrix ([]) for
>       [LOW HIGH], IMSHOW uses [min(I(:)) max(I(:))]; that is, the minimum value in
>       I is displayed as black, and the maximum value is displayed as white.

so `[]` is simply shorthand for `[min(pixel_labels(:)) max(pixel_labels(:))]`.